# Netbeans 8.2 throws 'Unexpected exception' after launching on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: netbeans

I use Netbeans IDE for dabbling in computer programming. Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my desktop and then installed OpenJDK. Then I installed Netbeans 8.2 (downloaded from official website).

Normally this should have been a pretty straight forward affair. But annoyingly, I have found that after launching, Netbeans is throwing 'Unexpected exception' error (with a red baloon in the right bottom corner). Then Netbeans remains inoperable. I can not begin new projects, can't activate features, can not edit options. Every click on each button simply results in nothing.

I tried uninstalling it and then reinstalling using umake. But that didn't change anything. After launching I even updated the IDE but that hasn't resolved the issue.

I will really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

Seems like I was being an unmitigated fool.

The problem was I had installed the ***wrong version of openjdk***. I had installed openjdk 11 while the Netbeans 8.2 required openjdk 8.

So I uninstalled the whole openjdk package from the system

'sudo apt remove - - purge openjdk*'

Then installed openjdk 8 by issuing

'sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre'

Then Netbeans (obviously) started working like a well-oiled machine as usual.

Sorry for the trouble folks.